# What does voice in writing mean?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when people talk about voice when referring to someone's writing? Is it his/her specific point of view? or Can two people have the same point of view and different writing voices?

Comment: You should begin by telling us your research on this ... what happened when you typed "writer voice" in Google, and why do you want more than that?

Comment: Thanks I will type "writer voice" in Google Thanks again!

Comment: A specific example that prompted you to ask the question would also be helpful. Grammatical voice, writer's voice, and character's voice could all be used when talking about someone's writing; it's not clear which one you mean.

Comment: You might try searching for [*voice* on Writers Stack Exchange.](http://writers.stackexchange.com/search?q=voice)

Answer (score 7):

In terms of writing, "voice" can mean several different things, depending on unpredictable variables.

1. It can mean "point of view", as Matthew points out. This is a **visual** metaphor
2. It can also mean "agency or lack of agency", in a metaphor with the Latin *(Inflected) Passive Voice*
   (which does not exist in English). This is a **grammatical** metaphor.
3. It can also mean — and this is the way *I* use it, at least, in writing about writing — the imagined voice of the author that the reader hears in their Mind's Ear as they go along. I read Terry Pratchett's books, for example, in what I fondly hope is a Buckinghamshire/Somerset accent. And I hear commas as intonation curves. This is an **auditory** metaphor.

Clearly, not everybody reads the same way. Literacy is modern technology — not naturally-evolved like real language — and not everybody realizes yet that writing is just transcribed speech — i.e, ***"voice"***. Everybody, as we all know, develops their own ways of dealing with technology, and writing is no exception.

Thus, I'm certain that I'm missing some senses. But the metaphor is clear:

> [**WRITING** is **SPEAKING**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf)

Comment: Well you certainly have a unique "written voice" - I don't think I've ever seen anyone else here on ELU use capitals that way in highlighted link text! What with all the other font formatting, your style here comes across as (almost wearily) spelling things out for your dullard scholars! You've said it here before, and I thoroughly agree - to a first approximation, writing is a form of speech. But there can be a "literary" dimension to writing that's some ways distant from normal vocal speech.

Comment: There are no doubt as many voices as there are people. Probably more. I wouldn't know about literature, only about writing; I tend more towards the crafts than the arts, I think. As for my written style, I try to write like I talk, as far as I can reproduce it.

Comment: Oh, almost forgot: the link capitals (small caps by preference) are fairly standard practice in talking about [Metaphor Themes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Comment: Oh, and about "dullard scholars" -- _Nah_. I **like** teaching -- to the extent this counts, that's what I (imagine I)'m doing. Like I say in my profile, I enjoy answering questions. When I can figure out what the question is, that is.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply otherwise - you might have spent your working life teaching just because you got paid for it, but you surely must enjoy it to be still here dispensing pearls of wisdom for free! I should have said "patiently" rather than "wearily". I just meant the substantial use of italics/bold/quotes/etc., which forces us to read more slowly and attentively, gives (me, at least) the impression that your "pedagogic voice" is intended to *engage* the audience as much as to *convey* the information (it "**sounds**" like a teacher's voice, even on screen! :)

Comment: Good. Like I said, I write like I talk, and vice versa. I've spent a lot of time explaining grammar in person -- far more time than I've ever spent writing about it, which is appropriate, given the relative importance of speech and writing.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm prolly *way* off-beam - in my "mind's ear", I imagine you sounding a bit like like a latter-day [Richard Feynman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SrHzSGn-I8). I find his style so "audience-engaging" that I truly believe I'm understanding every single word while he's actually speaking. It's only when someone asks me to explain it afterwards that I realise I haven't really grasped very much. But at least I can feel confident that *he* knows what he's talking about - theoretical physics is in principle comprehensible, even if it's too hard for me as a dilettante.

Comment: (I am though quite prepared to believe that language is more complex than quantum mechanics! :)

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. But I don't know; they're different things and require different skills, probably incommensurable.

Answer (score 2):

> [[Written] Voice:](https://twp.duke.edu/sites/twp.duke.edu/files/file-attachments/creative-writing-1.original.pdf) An author’s unique style and way of saying things. You should be able to recognize an author’s written voice the way you recognize a person’s spoken voice. In creative writing, one goal is to develop your written voice. Your voice should come across as natural, clear, and consistent, as unique to you as a fingerprint. Wordiness, awkward use of language, awkward sentence structure, and lack of clarity all serve to muffle the voice of the author.

In writing as in speech, "voice" is about *how* you express yourself - *style*, rather than *substance*.

A writer's "point of view" on any specific subject isn't necessarily relevant to how he expresses his views. If [Ernest Hemmingway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Hemingway) had ever changed his opinion about bullfighting and decided to disparage it, any such writing would still embody his distinctive "written voice" (characterised by short precise phrasing, omission of peripheral details, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Usually 'voice' means the 'point of view' that the prose is meant to convey.

So, for example, 'stream-of-consciousness voice' is meant to give you the thoughts of (usually) the narrator, from moment to moment.  'Character voice' is meant to convey that this is one person's (i.e. "character's") version of a story, where the character may or may not be central to the plot unfolding.